# i want sql query for one category have how much blogs?

Tags: mysql, php

blog table:

```
| bid  |  cname              |
______________________________
|  29  |  food,development   |
|  38  |  fashion            |
|  45  |  food               |
|  50  | fashion,business    |
```

categories table:

```
| cid   | cname        |
________________________
|  1    | food         |
|  2    | development  |
|  3    | business     |
|  4    | fashion      |
|  5    | health       |
```

i want output like:

```
| cname       | count  |
________________________
| food        |  2     |
| fashion     |  2     |
| development |  1     |
| business    |  1     |
| health      |  0     |
```

what will be sql query for this output?
i know this is bad normalized table but any how i want answer from this, is there any solution.
i am working on my project with php. any solution from php side too acceptable.

Comment: because you haven#t normalized your blog table, not very pretty

Comment: how can i normalize this table

Comment: this explains why storing data such as you is nit a good idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Answer (score 1):

If your tables are not big you can try this query:

```
SELECT c.cname 
    ,(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM blog WHERE FIND_IN_SET(c.cname, cname) > 0 ) AS count
FROM categories AS c
```

For large amount of data it may be better to normalize your tables and use indexes to join them. Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE blog_to_categories (
    bid int
    ,cid int
    ,PRIMARY KEY (bid, cid)
    ,KEY ix_blog_to_categories_cid (cid)
    ,CONSTRAINT fk_blog_to_categories_bid FOREIGN KEY (bid) REFERENCES blog (bid)
    ,CONSTRAINT fk_blog_to_categories_cid FOREIGN KEY (сid) REFERENCES categories (cid)
    );
```

1. fill blog_to_categories table with correspondig data
2. now you can remove cname column from blog table
3. and then use this query:

```
SELECT c.cname 
    ,COUNT(1) AS count
FROM categories AS c
LEFT JOIN blog_to_categories AS bc ON c.cid = bc.cid
GROUP BY c.cname;
```

Comment: thanks if you have any another solution for this?

Comment: @JainamDoshi I'm not sure what another solution do you mean but I updated the answer )